# <header> element smaller than contents hidding <nav><ul>...</ul></nav>

Tags: html, css

I have a `<header>` element in my page, but I am failing when trying to show its contents. it is a really simple header at the top of the page, with a navigation section. But the text on each `<li>` keeps going out of the header area, which is a problem as I have a dark background, and the text is outside.

`

```
header {
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

nav {
display: inline-block;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
right: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
color: #FFF;
}
a > span {
display: block;
}
```

`

---

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="http://link"> <img src="http://link/logo.png" alt="text"> </a>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="menu_1">
                <a href="http://link">Home<span>Text,text,text</span></a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu_2">
                <a href="http://link">Contact<span>Text,text,text</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the HTML also?

Comment: Need html too, Better make a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E69GU/

Comment: working here http://jsfiddle.net/KbLnv/

Comment: change the text color - because white on white is invisible ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KbLnv/2/

Comment: it is not, I have changed the background color so we could see.

Comment: color was not the only problem - the other problem was that your `nav` with position:absolute had not been set with correct height (100% doesn't work here - check 100px)...

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/KbLnv/3/

Comment: I see. Could you guys put this as an answer, so I can accept it. And just one more thing. I have used absolute, as a way to put it on the right, any guess how I keep that way, without float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
header {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

`position: absolute;`  in nav was creating a problem

Comment: I will have to "float" it then, won't I?